# Lambda capture (by value) of array is only copying the pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, lambda, capture

I'm trying to capture (by value) an entire C-style array.  The array seems to decay to a pointer... How do I prevent this so that the whole array is captured?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char x[1024];

    std::cerr << sizeof(x) << "\n";
    [x = x] // copy
    {
        std::cerr << sizeof(x) << "\n";
    }();
}
```

This prints:

```
1024  <<-- yay
8     <<-- oops... not a true copy
```

It should be noted that this works as I had hoped (1024 for both results):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::array<char, 1024> x;

    std::cerr << sizeof(x) << "\n";
    [x = x] // copy
    {
        std::cerr << sizeof(x) << "\n";
    }();
}
```

Comment: Arrays are second class citizens of C++. They resist being copied, presumably because a long time ago it would have been considered unusual, and probably a mistake. I didn't know it would decay to pointer in a lambda capture, but it isn't surprising to me. If you want an `array` object in C++, I would suggest sticking with `std::array` which rarely surprises.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [x = x]

This one is equal to

```
auto x1 = x;
```

Which is actually decay to a pointer.

Just change your lambda capture to `[x]` to capture `x` by value. Also you can capture it by reference with `[&x]`.